# Using CSS to make two links fade in when hovering over a different link

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions, fade

This might be pushing the limits of CSS hover transitions (it's certainly pushing the limits of my novice understanding) but here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a menu bar along top of the screen, and there's a "Home" link there. When you hover over it, two additional links--"Writings" and "Music"--should appear above and below "Home", respectively.

Not just appear, though... I want them to fade in from invisible to visible. And when you leave the area, they fade back out and disappear.

Actually, the two links should probably fade in when your mouse hovers over the whole list, since I don't want them disappearing when your mouse leaves "home" and tries to click "writings" or "music".

Anyway, what I tried hasn't worked. Right now nothing happens. The two extra links stay invisible and nothing changes when I hover over.

Note: I have borders around the list so I can track everything easier (I'm kinda new).

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}

ins {
 text-decoration: none;
}
del {
 text-decoration: line-through;
}

table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}


/* MY CODE BELOW */

.header {  /* MENU BAR ACROSS THE TOP */
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 width: 100%;
 height: 150px;
 background-color: black;
 opacity: 0.8;
 position: absolute;
    left : 0;
 align-items: center;
 

}

.home {   /* LIST CONTAINER */
 border: 1px solid red;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 margin-left: 5%;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'heebo';
 font-size: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100px;
}

.home ul{  /* LIST O' LINKS */
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid green;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.homeW{  /* 'WRITINGS' LINK */
 border: 1px solid yellow;
 text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.homeH{   /* 'HOME' LINK */
 border: 1px solid purple;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.homeM{  /* 'MUSIC' LINK */
 border: 1px solid pink;
 text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.homeH:hover .homeW {   /* ON 'HOME' HOVER, 'WRITINGS' APPEARS */
 opacity: 1.0;
    transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
}

.homeH:hover .homeM {  /* ...AND SO DOES 'MUSIC' */
 opacity: 1.0;
    transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
}

.header a {   /* LINKS ARE WHITE (WHEN THEY ARE VISIBLE) */
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
 
 <div class="home">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a class="homeW" href="#">Writing</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a class="homeH" href="#">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a class="homeM" href="#">Music</a>
   </li>
          </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a lot of css.  It would help others answer if you can get the smallest set of code possible to demonstrate your question.

Comment: The first half is a reset. My stuff starts at /* My Code Below */ . I left the reset in because the sizes were all weird and the list had bullets without it.

Comment: I feel that this can't be made just with CSS. Might need JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't affect siblings if they are before the hovered element in DOM order. Instead, check for the whole list to be hovered, see your updated snippet below.

Further explanation: Starting with your list

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="homeW" href="#">Writing</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="homeH" href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="homeM" href="#">Music</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Your link `a.homeH` is inside an `li` element. CSS currently does not support any parent selector. Your selector `.homeH:hover .homeW` would only affect an element with class `.homeW` that's a child of another element with class `.homeH` while being hovered.

Even if your `li` elements would have the same class, you could only do `li.homeH:hovered ~ li.homeM`, that would be applied to the Music bullet point (`~` is the siblings selector), but it wouldn't work for Writing since that list item is *BEFORE* the actual home list item.

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
ins {
  text-decoration: none;
}
del {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
/* MY CODE BELOW */

.header {
  /* MENU BAR ACROSS THE TOP */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  align-items: center;
}
.home {
  /* LIST CONTAINER */
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 5%;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'heebo';
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}
.home ul {
  /* LIST O' LINKS */
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.homeW {
  /* 'WRITINGS' LINK */
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.homeH {
  /* 'HOME' LINK */
  border: 1px solid purple;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.homeM {
  /* 'MUSIC' LINK */
  border: 1px solid pink;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.home:hover .homeW {
  /* ON 'HOME' HOVER, 'WRITINGS' APPEARS */
  opacity: 1.0;
  transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
}
.home:hover .homeM {
  /* ...AND SO DOES 'MUSIC' */
  opacity: 1.0;
  transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
}
.header a {
  /* INKS ARE WHITE (WHEN THEY ARE VISIBLE) */
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <div class="home">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="homeW" href="#">Writing</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="homeH" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="homeM" href="#">Music</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 100% solution but you can do this on `hover` on element `ul`

```
.home ul:hover li a{opacity: 1.0 !important; }
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}

ins {
 text-decoration: none;
}
del {
 text-decoration: line-through;
}

table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}


/* MY CODE BELOW */

.header {  /* MENU BAR ACROSS THE TOP */
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 width: 100%;
 height: 150px;
 background-color: black;
 opacity: 0.8;
 position: absolute;
    left : 0;
 align-items: center;
 

}

.home {   /* LIST CONTAINER */
 border: 1px solid red;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 margin-left: 5%;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'heebo';
 font-size: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100px;
}

.home ul{  /* LIST O' LINKS */
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid green;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.homeW{  /* 'WRITINGS' LINK */
 border: 1px solid yellow;
 text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.homeH{   /* 'HOME' LINK */
 border: 1px solid purple;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.homeM{  /* 'MUSIC' LINK */
 border: 1px solid pink;
 text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.homeH:hover .homeW {   /* ON 'HOME' HOVER, 'WRITINGS' APPEARS */
 opacity: 1.0;
    transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
}

.homeH:hover .homeM {  /* ...AND SO DOES 'MUSIC' */
 opacity: 1.0;
    transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
}

.header a {   /* LINKS ARE WHITE (WHEN THEY ARE VISIBLE) */
 color: white;
}
.home ul:hover li a{opacity: 1.0 !important; }
```

```html
<div class="header">
 
 <div class="home">
  <ul>
           
   <li>
    <a class="homeW" href="#">Writing</a>
   </li>
      <li>
    <a class="homeH" href="#">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a class="homeM" href="#">Music</a>
   </li>
        
          
          </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation - 100% desired effect

#### HTML

1. Moved the classes from the anchor tag `<a>` to the outer list-item `<li>` tag.
2. I moved the `Home` list-item to the top, and changed the position of the

#### CSS

1. Used the `~` CSS selector to select the subsequent siblings.
2. Altered `margin`

### Code

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
ins {
  text-decoration: none;
}
del {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
/* MY CODE BELOW */

.header {
  /* MENU BAR ACROSS THE TOP */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  align-items: center;
}
.home {
  /* LIST CONTAINER */
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 5%;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'heebo';
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}
.home ul {
  /* LIST O' LINKS */
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.homeW {
  /* 'WRITINGS' LINK */
  margin:-60px 0px 30px 0px;/*----- added margin -----*/
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.homeH {
  /* 'HOME' LINK */
  margin-top: 30px; /*-----added margin-----*/
  border: 1px solid purple;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.homeM {
  /* 'MUSIC' LINK */
  border: 1px solid pink;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.homeH:hover .homeW {
  /* ON 'HOME' HOVER, 'WRITINGS' APPEARS */
  opacity: 1.0;
  transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
}
.homeH:hover ~ li { /*----- added ~ CSS selector-----*/
  /* ...AND SO DOES 'MUSIC' */
  opacity: 1.0;
  transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
}
.header a {
  /* LINKS ARE WHITE (WHEN THEY ARE VISIBLE) */
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <div class="home">
    <ul>
      <li class="homeH">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="homeW">
        <a href="#">Writing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="homeM">
        <a href="#">Music</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```